# NoSuchMethodError at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector

Tags: android

My application is use google maps. It's well for most of the devices. But on some unknown device(s) it's throws exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.ViewConfiguration.getScaledDoubleTapTouchSlop
at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.init(GestureDetector.java:393)
at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:354)
at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.<init>(GestureDetector.java:329)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.setup(MapView.java:330)
at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.setupMapView(MapActivity.java:404)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:289)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
at mypackage.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:43)
... 41 more
```

Project target is Google APIs Platform 4.0, API level 14.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem with one of my applications which use googlemaps. It is running fine on an AndroVM and the ADK simulator, but crash with the same missing method on my Nextbook 7 which has been modified with Finless ROM. I've done further investigation using "baksmali" tool to figure out that the /system/framework/framework.jar on my NextBook was different from others, the method was effectively missing.

So, maybe the framework.jar on your device is also culprit ...

Update : I've finally got it !
I took a newer /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar from ADK emulator instead of keeping the one from Cyanogen which was dated from 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have compiled this method with the compiler who understands it.But it is not understood by the JVM at runtime.(Incompatibility issues).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the application has been run on an old Android version (under 4.0). So when the method is called in your code, you got an `NoSuchMethodError` because the method doesn't exists in previous API.

EDIT: Should be ok because the method is since API 3, but maybe you missed some imports ?

Answer (score 0):

Update : I've finally got it !
I took a newer /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar from ADK emulator instead of keeping the one from Cyanogen which was outdated from 2008.